# matplotlib/seaborn violin plot with colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colormap, violin-plot

I want to create a violin plot, with either matplotlib or searborn, in which the plot is colored according to a colormap.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I would like to get (I used Photoshop here):
[image]

How can I obtain the desired plot?

Comment: Is the colormap just for aesthetics, or is the mapping important? Do you want the color to be scaled to the y-axis values, or something else?

Comment: the mapping is important, I use it to compare the violin plot with some other plots

Comment: But in that case you would want to tell people what quantity you want to have mapped to colors.

Comment: The meaning of the colors are explained by the color map, anyway what is important is how the colors, that are used in other plots, are distributed (this is why I use a violin plot)

Comment: Not sure if I understand that; so the only thing I can say here is that you will need to create an `imshow` with the desired mapping and use the violin's outlines as `clip_path` to the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought there would be a better was to do this, but, based on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, I guess this is actually the way to go:

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable


x = [np.random.normal(loc=i, scale=1, size=(100,)) for i in range(5)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
violins = ax.violinplot(x)

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

# create a numpy image to use as a gradient
Nx,Ny=1,1000
imgArr = np.tile(np.linspace(0,1,Ny), (Nx,1)).T
cmap = 'hsv'

for violin in violins['bodies']:
    path = Path(violin.get_paths()[0].vertices)
    patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    img = ax.imshow(imgArr, origin="lower", extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax], aspect="auto",
                    cmap=cmap,
                    clip_path=patch)

# colorbar
ax_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = ax_divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad="2%")
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=ymin, vmax=ymax)
cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(cmap),
                                norm=norm,
                                orientation='vertical')
```

[image]

Comment: How could I get also a vertical bar on the side of the plot showing the color gradient? I tried adding a rectangle but it does not work, I think I have to have a patch which is the "inverse" of a rectangle

Comment: sure, you can create a colorbar using `ColorbarBase` and the appropriate normalization. I've amended my answer