# How can you colour a matplotlib plot to show point density?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting some partial dependency plots using matplotlib. I have 1,000 samples which I produce regression predictions for. These predictions are plotted on the y-axis. To get an overview of partial dependency for the whole dataset I'm fixing all variables in my samples bar one. The un-fixed variable is shown on the x-axis and is varied for all samples.

On my plot I want to show the mean value that my 1,000 samples take for a given x value, and the distribution of values plotted as a colour gradient at that x value. At the moment I have the following:

[image: Demonstration of point method.]

This is functional, because it shows the density of predictions for a given x value, but ugly. I want something that does the same job of showing density at each x value, but that is a smooth gradient that fills the plot, not individual points.

How would I achieve something like this?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/.  The seaborn library has good defaults and uses matplotlib for plotting

Comment: Rather than using colour to show the density you could use a violin plot (via [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html#seaborn.violinplot) or directly through the [matplotlib interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## sns.histplot with default colormap

One option is the latest version of seaborn's `sns.histplot()` for 2d data.

Here is an example, tested with seaborn 0.13.2:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240220)
y = 1.1 ** (80 + np.abs(np.random.randn(10000).cumsum()))
x = np.repeat([*'abcde'], len(y) // 5)

sns.histplot(x=x, y=y, log_scale=(False, True), discrete=(True, False))
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with categorical data in x]

## sns.histplot using a colormap with alpha values

You can create a custom colormap with transparency values and use that.  The effect only works well on a white background.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, to_rgba
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240220)
y = 1.1 ** (80 + np.abs(np.random.randn(10000).cumsum()))
x = np.repeat([*'abcde'], len(y) // 5)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('blue-alpha',
                                         [to_rgba('dodgerblue', alpha=.2),
                                          to_rgba('dodgerblue', alpha=1)])
ax = sns.histplot(x=x, y=y, log_scale=True, cmap=cmap)
ax.set_facecolor('white')
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot using colormap with transparencies]

## A scatter plot with a line marker

A very different approach would be to use a horizontal line as marker (instead of the default circular dot). As the x limits don't take large scatter dots into account, they need to be updated manually.

```py
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=4000, marker='_', alpha=0.03)
plt.xlim(-0.5, len(plt.xticks()[0]) - 0.5)
```

[image: scatter plot with line marker]

Comment: That looks good! Is there a way to do it with alpha values as well?

Comment: I added two extra versions: one with `sns.histplot` with semi-transparent colors. And one scatterplot using horizontal lines as marker.

Comment: I love the second one! I think I'll use that, thank you. Happy to accept, but do you know of any other way of producing this sort of plot? I swear I've seen something that looked really nice like this before, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can use `imshow()`, with or without clipping, as shown in @MattPitkin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323884/matplotlib-seaborn-violin-plot-with-colormap), and using some kernel density estimation, (and assuming you are happy with a [violin-style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot.html) plot!) you could do something equivalent to the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import matplotlib as mpl

import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde


# create KDE
def kde(values, npoints=100):
    vals = np.linspace(values.min(), values.max(), npoints, endpoint=True)

    # generate and evaluate the KDE
    return gaussian_kde(values)(vals)


data = [np.random.normal(loc=i, scale=1, size=(100,)) for i in range(3)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
violins = ax.violinplot(data, showextrema=False)

# get colour map
cmap = mpl.colormaps["Blues"]

# number of point to evaluate a Gaussian KDE
npoints = 100

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

# loop over each violin
for i, violin in enumerate(violins["bodies"]):
    # get extent of violin
    extent = violin.get_datalim(ax.transData)

    # add new patch surrounding the violin
    path = Path(violin.get_paths()[0].vertices)
    patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor="none", edgecolor="none")
    violin.set_visible(False)  # make original violin invisible
    ax.add_patch(patch)

    # create image to show the gradient
    cvalues = np.atleast_2d(kde(data[i], npoints)).T
    img = ax.imshow(
        cvalues,
        origin="lower",
        extent=[extent.xmin, extent.xmax, extent.ymin, extent.ymax],
        cmap=cmap,
        aspect="auto",
        clip_path=patch,
    )

# reset axes ranges
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

This gives:

[image]

You could do this with [rectangular patches](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) that you create yourself based on the data extent, if you don't want the violin-style.